# JQuery; target and fire function only if in a certain directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, directory, pathname

OK the results of my script aren't exactly producing the answer I am looking and the variable is coming back the opposite of what I am looking for:

//REVISED:This is in the mouseOut of .hover()

Here is my function:

```
$(".about,.activeAbout").hover(
  function () {
    $('#dropInvestments').css( "left","-9999px" );
    $('#dropMedia').css( "left","-9999px" );
    $('#dropAbout').css( "left","415px" );
    $('#aboutTitle').addClass("aboutTitleActive").removeClass("aboutTitle");
  }, 
      function () {
      $pageLoc = document.location.pathname.split('/about/');
      alert($pageLoc);
      if (document.location.pathname == $pageLoc) 

    {
      $('#aboutTitle').addClass("aboutTitle").removeClass("aboutTitleActive");
    }

}
);
```

Here is the pathname:

```
wga/x3/about/history.html
```

What i want is to only do the class change if the current page is not in the about folder/directory. Any thoughts?

Using split takes out the about and returns the pathname without it...

Comment: Although there are probably better ways to check for this, your `$pageLoc` will always be an array, and if the original string contained "/about/" in it, the array's length will be > 1. So I think you could just use that

Comment: How about giving a checkmark for the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

User regex `.test` to do this:

```
function () {
    var pattern = /^\/?wga\/x3\/about\/.*/;
    if (pattern.test(document.location.pathname)) {
        $('#aboutTitle').addClass("aboutTitle").removeClass("aboutTitleActive");
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer pointed me in the right direction SO THANK YOU but it did not solve the problem. I have figured it out thanks to your direction. I will post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Mad Thanks to Ohgodwhy and TheSmose for pointing me in the right direction, Here is how I got it to work. If you can make it simpler or have a better way feel free to post. Thank You:

```
$(".about,.activeAbout").hover(
  function () {
    $('#dropInvestments').css( "left","-9999px" );
    $('#dropMedia').css( "left","-9999px" );
    $('#dropAbout').css( "left","415px" );
    $('#aboutTitle').addClass("aboutTitleActive").removeClass("aboutTitle");
  }, 
  function () {
      $pageLoc = document.location.pathname;
      $tarLoc = /about/g;
      $result = $tarLoc.test($pageLoc);
      if ($result !== true) 

    {
      $('#aboutTitle').addClass("aboutTitle").removeClass("aboutTitleActive");
    }

  }
);
```

Comment: That won't work. It will match any page with the word "about" in the url.  So let's say you add `/wga/x3/services/about-our-services.html` in the future... it'll match that, as well.  The answer I posted above is what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried your code but it did not produce the result I was looking for... thank you